# Cannot resolve Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start() Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I've trouble to resolve the following exception
"Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka"

My code is the following :

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate()

val bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
val topicName = "name"

val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", topicName)
      .option("group.id", "Structured-Streaming-kpi")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .load()

df.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination();
df.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is this
`df.show()`

Your df is written to console already.

Try to remove it and see what happens